# the code line doesn't enter into de switch-case

Tags: c, programming-languages

i'm starting to use C language, but till now i have some mistakes, I got a code but when i;m running it, he suddenly returns to the beginning without enter into the swicth-case, what could i do to solve it,i'm using the PIC18f4550 from microchip and the MPLAB and C18 compiler. thanks for your timeand consideration. her's the code:

```
void SECUENCIA_1();
void SECUENCIA_2();
void SECUENCIA_3();
void SECUENCIA_4();
void SECUENCIA_5();
void SECUENCIA_6();
void SECUENCIA_ERROR();
void SALIDA_OK();
int i;
unsigned char COMBINACION;

void main(void) {
ADCON1 = 0x0F;
PORTA  = 0x00;
TRISA  = 0b00000;
PORTC  = 0x00;
TRISC  = 0b11100000;
PORTD  = 0x00;
TRISD  = 0b110000;
PORTE  = 0x00;
TRISE  = 0b000;
PORTB  = 0x00;
TRISB  = 0b11111111; 


COMBINACION = 0x00;
COMBINACION = COMBINACION | (PORTCbits.RC5);
COMBINACION = COMBINACION << 1;
COMBINACION = COMBINACION | (PORTCbits.RC4);
COMBINACION = COMBINACION << 1;
COMBINACION = COMBINACION | (PORTDbits.RD3);


switch (COMBINACION)
{
case 0x0: SECUENCIA_ERROR; break;
case 0x1: SECUENCIA_1; break;
case 0x2: SECUENCIA_2; break;
case 0x3: SECUENCIA_3; break;
case 0x4: SECUENCIA_4; break;
case 0x5: SECUENCIA_5; break;
case 0x6: SECUENCIA_6; break;
default:SECUENCIA_ERROR;
}
}
.
.
.
.
```

the code continue after this sentence but I don't know why it only return after setting the last value of "COMBINACION"

Comment: `SECUENCIA_ERROR` is an expression that evaluates to a function pointer and does nothing. If you want to call the void function without parameters, use `SECUENCIA_ERROR()`, with empty parentheses appended. (This is different from Pascal, for example, where your syntax does call the procedure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `()` in your function calls.

Without `()`, a function name is treated as a function pointer instead of a function call in C.

So add `()` like this:

```
switch (COMBINACION)
{
    case 0x0: SECUENCIA_ERROR(); break;
    case 0x1: SECUENCIA_1(); break;
    case 0x2: SECUENCIA_2(); break;
    case 0x3: SECUENCIA_3(); break;
    case 0x4: SECUENCIA_4(); break;
    case 0x5: SECUENCIA_5(); break;
    case 0x6: SECUENCIA_6(); break;
    default:SECUENCIA_ERROR();
}
```